# Boost Threads and Timers, C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer, boost-asio

I have this code for a custom class 'sau_timer':

```
sau_timer::sau_timer(int secs, timerparam f, vector<string> params) : strnd(io), 
    t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(secs))
{
    assert(secs > 0);
    this->f = f;
    this->params = params;
    t.async_wait(strnd.wrap(boost::bind(&sau_timer::exec, this, _1)));
    boost::thread thrd(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
    io.run();
}

void sau_timer::exec(const boost::system::error_code&) {
    (f)(params);
}
```

I want it so that when I make a sau_timer object, the timer will start, but allow program execution to continue. For example, this is main():

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<string> args(1);
    args[0] = "Hello!";
    sau_timer timer_test(3, sau_prompt, args);
    args[0] = "First!";
    sau_prompt(args);
    timer_test.thrd.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My intention here is that timer_test is made, starting a timer that waits three seconds before calling sau_prompt("Hello!"), but that sau_prompt("First!") will be called first. At the moment, Hello is shown in the prompt before First, indicating that the timer is halting the entire program for three seconds before allowing it to continue. I want the timer to run in the background.

What am I doing wrong? The code compiles...

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You're calling "io.run()" in sau_timer - that essentially tells the asio reactor to process any/all pending async events if it can.

You should call run or post after the having setup the events, which is how its normally done. check out the examples in the asio documentation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>


class event_timer
{
public:

   event_timer(asio::io_service& io_service,
               const std::size_t& tid,
               const std::size_t& interval = 5)
   : io_service_(io_service),
     timer_(io_service),
     tid_(tid),
     interval_(interval),
     tick_count_(0),
     total_diff_(0)
   {
   }

   void start()
   {
      timer_.cancel();
      initiate_timer();
   }

   void stop()
   {
      timer_.cancel();
   }

   void set_interval(const std::size_t& milliseconds)
   {
      interval_ = milliseconds;
   }

private:

   inline void initiate_timer()
   {
      if (interval_)
      {
         timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(interval_));
         timer_.async_wait(
            boost::bind(&event_timer::handle_timer_event,this,
               asio::placeholders::error));
         before_ = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
      }
   }

   inline void handle_timer_event(const asio::error_code& error)
   {
      if (!error && interval_)
      {
         after_ = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
         boost::posix_time::time_duration duration = after_ - before_;
         total_diff_ += std::abs(interval_ - duration.total_milliseconds());
         ++tick_count_;
         if (tick_count_ < 200)
            initiate_timer();
         else
            std::cout << "Timer["<< tid_ <<"]\tTick["<< tick_count_ <<"] Average Diff: " << total_diff_ / (1.0 * tick_count_) << std::endl;
      }
   }

   asio::io_service& io_service_;
   std::size_t tid_;
   std::size_t interval_;
   std::size_t tick_count_;
   asio::deadline_timer timer_;
   boost::posix_time::ptime before_;
   boost::posix_time::ptime after_;
   std::size_t total_diff_;
};

int main()
{

   std::cout << "Timer Test" << std::endl;

   asio::io_service io_service;

   try
   {
      const std::size_t et_cnt = 1000;
      std::vector<event_timer*> et_lst;

      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < et_cnt; ++i)
      {
         et_lst.push_back(new event_timer(io_service,i,10));
      }

      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < et_cnt;)
      {
         et_lst[i++]->start();
      }

      std::size_t thread_pool_size = 100;

      //Create a pool of threads to run all of the io_services.
      std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; ++i)
      {
         boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&asio::io_service::run, &io_service)));
         threads.push_back(thread);
      }

      // Wait for all threads in the pool to exit.
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threads.size(); ++i)
         threads[i]->join();
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < et_cnt; delete et_lst[i++]);

   }
   catch(std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I put  timer_test.io.run(); under the line sau_timer timer_test(3, sau_prompt, args); in main(), and removed the io.run() from the class constructor, but the effect is still the same. I fear I've misunderstood?

Comment: The example code should be enough for you to understand how asio should be used in general. You see the idea is not to create threads to run is objects say a timer or a reciever object, but rather to create multiple threads that run io_services, and to let those threaded io_services run async calls in a threaded/concurrent manner.

Answer (score 0):

considering namespace and boost version 1.69, there are three modifications should be done:

1. change `#include <asio.hpp>` into `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`
2. add: `using namespace boost;  using namespace boost:asio;`
3. change `inline void handle_timer_event(const asio::error_code& error)` into `void handle_timer_event(const boost::system::error_code& error)`